# Giving user option to select extended permissions

Tags: facebook

I'm making a application for facebook that will be used for academic research. Right now when the user goes to install the application I'll request additional information which is stated in the extended permissions.

I would perfectly understand someone not wanting to give out certain aspects of this information (It's just used to gather statistics about people taking part , education, religion etc.)

Does anyone know the best way to filter the permissions? For instance maybe someone is willing to give their age but not education. Therefore can I remove the education request from my application install request dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ask the user for only those permissions that he wants to give, you can take input from him before redirecting to Facebook login. You can generate the url for requesting permissions based on this custom set of permissions using the 'perms' attribute of the `<fb:loginbutton />` tag or pass the list of permissions you want to the `$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => $perms))` call.

To keep track of permission changes, you can use the realtime updates offered. You can know more about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly could build an up-front permissions matrix that the user could cherry-pick from. And that would probably be the way to do it, since you can't do anything to customize the permission challenge that the Facebook Platform generates.

The trick would be keeping track of which permissions the user granted in the given access token you'll receive from back from the Platform.  Especially since users can change the permissions granted to your application w/o visiting the application itself - so you'll want to be hooked in to that info via the [Real Time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime).